# Can't call PHP to page

Tags: php, html, blogs

I'm trying to call a php snippet to load a miniblog.
The code provided by the site is:

```
<?php
    define('IN_BLOG', true);
    define('PATH', '../miniblog');
    include('includes/miniblog.php');
?>
```

I have tried calling it both in index.php and sidebar.php in the table cell I want it to go in, in the header, and in the body.

I keep getting warnings like:

> Warning: include(includes/miniblog.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/a1822199/public_html/index.php on line 32

EDIT: I was asked to include some code, this is my index page. I have installed the plug in as the site says, and it's accepting blog posts.

```
<body>
    <table width="75%" align="center" id="container">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="25%">
                <?php
                    define('IN_BLOG', true);
                    define('PATH', '../miniblog');
                    include('includes/miniblog.php');
                ?>
                <?php include 'sidebar.php'; ?></td>
            <td width="75%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

EDIT 2:

It seems to be searching in index.php as if IT ITSELF is a folder.

Comment: `include(PATH.'includes/miniblog.php');`

Comment: Well the error is clear enough. You try to include a file that doesn't exist. Double check your path.

Comment: The problem I'm having is it always seems to look in index.php for a subset of files, I can't get it to look in its directory.

Comment: the error is clearly describes here. Where is your `miniblog.php` situated? the absolute path??

Comment: @Arun - miniblog/includes/miniblog.php

Comment: Where is that miniblog directory relatively to index.html ?

Comment: site root / index : site root / miniblog / includes / miniblog.php

Comment: I've added the answser

Comment: By the way, it's not telling you index.php is a folder, it's telling you that the error is in that file on the given line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `include('miniblog/includes/miniblog.php');`

Comment: I had tried that previously, and once again on your recommendation. But thank you for your effort. Its lovely to see someone giving a hand out to a beginner :)

Comment: What do you see when you put that in your index.php and load the page : `$currentDirectory = getcwd();   $files = scandir($currentDirectory);   print_r($files);`

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_connect() in /home/a1822199/public_html/miniblog/includes/miniblog.php on line 14

Comment: So, it did find your miniblog.php finally, you have another problem though but this question is answered ;)

Comment: Oh, right, Brilliant :D Thanks. half the battle won :D

Answer (score 0):

see `/home/a1822199/public_html/index.php` this is your path to `index.php` and I think

```
`/home/a1822199/public_html/`
```

will be the path to `includes` folder. And you says that the file situated in

```
`miniblog/includes/miniblog.php`
```

pleasse give the absolute path like

```
 `http://localhost/miniblog/includes/miniblog.php`
```

If the directory structure is like this.

Comment: I tried this and a few other variations such as using the url in lieu of localhost(which I assumed you meant) and using /home as the route, no avail I'm afraid. But thank you for your effort

Comment: with pleasure to help